# Why prefix returns documents without the specific prefix?

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to return only documents which their name start with "pizza". this is what I've done:

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "prefix": {
          "name": "pizza"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But I've got these 3 documents:

```
{
"name": "Viana Pizza",
"city": "Mashhad",
"address": "Vakil abad",
"foods": ["Pizza"],
"salad": true,
"rate": 5.0
}

{
"name": "Pizza Pizza",
"city": "Mashhad",
"address": "Bahar st",
"foods": ["Pizza"],
"salad": true,
"rate": 8.5
}

{
"name": "Reza Pizza",
"city": "Tehran",
"address": "Vali Asr",
"foods": ["Pizza"],
"salad": true,
"rate": 7.5
}
```

As you can see, Only one of them has "pizza" in the beginning of the name field.
What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably, the simplest explanation given that you didn't provide the actual mapping, is that you have th e "name" field as "string" and "analyzed" (the default). Which means that "Reza Pizza" will be transformed to "reza" and "pizza" terms.

And your filter will match against terms, not against entire fields. Because ES analyzes the fields and forms terms when the standard mapping is used.

You need to either change your "name" field to "not_analyzed" or add another field to mirror the "name" but this mirror field to be "not_analyzed". Also, for text "pizza" (lowercase) to work in this case you need to create a custom analyzer.

Below you have the solution with the mirror field:

```
PUT /pizza
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_keyword_lowercase_analyzer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "keyword",
          "filter": ["lowercase"]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "restaurant": {
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "string",
          "fields": {
            "raw": {
              "type": "string",
              "analyzer": "my_keyword_lowercase_analyzer"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And in searching you need to use the mirror field:

```
GET /pizza/restaurant/_search
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "prefix": {
          "name.raw": "pizza"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

That's all about Elasticsearch [analyzers](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-analyzers.html). Let's read the [documentation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-prefix-filter.html) on `prefix` filter:

```
Filters documents that have fields containing terms with a specified prefix (not analyzed).
```

Here we can see that this filter matches **terms**, not the whole field value. When you index the document, ES splits your field values to terms using analyzers. Default analyzer splits value by whitespace and convert parts to lowercse. So all three results have term **pizza** in the name field and `pizza` term perfectly matches `pizza` prefix. If you want to match field value as is - I'd suggest you to map name field as `not_analyzed`